# How to convert object to generic

Tags: c#, type-conversion

If I get some values from the database in C#, they are type object. Now I want to convert this values `typesafe` to load them into my object which represents a `datarow` more or less. So I thought it would be nice to create a generic extend-method for extend object.

So I build the following:

```
public static T ConvertToType<T>(this object value)
{
   T returnValue = default(T);
   if (value != DBNull.Value)
   {
      returnValue = (T)value;
   }

   return returnValue;
}
```

So I can use this to convert the different values from the given `datarow` and if the database stores `null` value I get the default type.

For example:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
   MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
   myObject.Id = row["ID"].ConvertToType<int>();
}
```

This works for compile time but it seems not possible to cast object to `int` for example. So I thought all value types have to be handled manually.

So I extend the first Code-Block:

```
public static T ConvertToType<T>(this object value)
{
   T returnValue = default(T);
   if (value != DBNull.Value)
   {
      if (wert is int)
      {
        rueckgabe = Convert.ToInt32(wert);
      }
      //else if All Value-Types are following...
      else
      {
        returnValue = (T)value;
      }
   }

   return returnValue;
}
```

But for sure the compiler now tells me that target type T can't be converted to `int`. This is quite clear.

Is someone out there who got a well solution for this issue? Or is this not as simple as I hoped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been implemented.

you can do `row.Field<int>("ID")`

the extension method is under `System.Data` namespace

for nullable fields, you can do `row.Field<int?>("ID")` since .Field returns null instead of `default(T)` for DBNull

Comment: can't find in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @Sebi did you include the namespace? Based on MSDN this exists as early as .Net 3.5

Comment: found it ;) I have to include the dll System.Data.DataSetExtension. Thought System.Data would be enough. Thanks thats great :)

Comment: This Method isnt working as expected i guess. If i got value "1" in my dataRow this cant be casted to int. This should be possible i think.

Comment: only if the db field also represents an integer.

Comment: @Jan UnId ah ok...our DataTable just got object values stored. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
[Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        if (value is T)
        {
            returnValue = (T)value;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                returnValue = default(T);
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Maybe you should think of not catching the InvalidCastException here. If you can imagine that the default type-value could be of some use in your program it could be better to let the calling method handle the exception.